# My Friend James

Tags: story, language

I have a friend named James*. James is the victim of an unfortunate circumstance which prevents him from doing something that most of you can do.

**Which unfortunate lack of ability would explain the following misconceptions that James has?**

- James doesn't understand the difference between a trash can and a belt.
- James thinks that kings helped mosquitoes reproduce.
- James thinks that cylinder locks have ink in them.
- James believes that the atmosphere will possess his father's estate.
- James brings a Ferris Wheel and a stick of cotton candy when he wants to ride a bus.

*<sub>Not a real person.</sub>

Comment: Also, cylinder locks or cinder blocks? Lol I read it wrong probably four times before I noticed.

Comment: @PerpetualJ cylinder locks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

James has difficulty

> distinguishing homophones. A belt holds your *waist*, while a trash can holds your *waste*. Mosquitos thrive in the *rain*, but a king's *reign* doesn't control the weather. He thinks locks have *pens* in them, when they actually have *pins*. He believes that the *air* is an *heir*, and that you need a *fair* when you really need a *fare*.

Comment: Beat me to it - I had exactly the same ones and am missng the same two! +1

Comment: I think 2 is about rot13(ervta juvpu vf n ubzbcubar sbe enva)

Comment: Seems likely that 3 is: rot13(craf va gur ybpx vafgrnq bs cvaf)

Comment: I thought of that too but looks weird because they are not really rot13(ubzbcubarf) in the sense... but it could be correct depending on how you pronounce.

Comment: @Supersonic rm-vanda is correct - here in the Midwest US, the difference is hardly discernible when spoken. Now that I think about it, though, there is definitely a difference between the two. Sorry about that. Also you have #2 correct as well.

Comment: @Brandon_J Thanks for the clarification! Also, a really small discrepancy like this doesn't hurt the puzzle quality IMO. This is a very nice puzzle! :)

Comment: @Brandon_J Thanks! So, maybe #2 is about rot13( xavtugf naq avtug)

Comment: I'm pretty sure #2 is rot13(ervta naq enva)

Comment: Perhaps #3 is rot13( zbegvfr qvr naq oynpx qlr )...  Nope, ignore that... OP states otherwise in comments above.

Answer (score 20):

StephenTG has the correct answer. Just to finish off the full explanation by solving the remaining clues:

1. James doesn't understand the difference between a trash can and a belt.

   > A trash can holds your **waste**; a belt holds your **waist**.
2. James thinks that kings helped mosquitoes reproduce.

   > Kings **reign**; mosquitoes reproduce in **rain**.
3. James thinks that cylinder locks have ink in them.

   > **Penn** cylinder locks, a **pen** has ink in it.
4. James believes that the atmosphere will possess his father's estate.

   > **Air** makes up the atmosphere; the **heir** will possess an estate.
5. James brings a Ferris Wheel and a stick of cotton candy when he wants to ride a bus.

   > A **fair** has a ferris wheel and a stick of cotton candy; a **fare** is needed to ride a bus.